# Supported audio file formats in AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

Where can I find list of all supported audio formats in AVAudioPlayer? I tried to find any information about it in docs, but I couldn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation of AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer),

> This class lets you play sound in any audio format available in iOS
> and macOS.

And here is the link from [CoreAudio documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX.html) that describes the supported audio file formats in OS X.

[image: Supported Audio Formats]